# Why does Buildozer show `# Aidl not found, please install it.` even after I installed it?

Tags: java, android, kivy, buildozer, aidl

I have installed build-essential, libstdc++6,and, aidl itself:

```
sudo apt-get install aidl 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aspectj eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp fastjar fping jarwrapper junit4
  kivy-doc kivy-tools libasm3-java libasm4-java libaspectj-java libcglib3-java
  libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-httpclient-java
  libeasymock-java libequinox-osgi-java libfelix-bundlerepository-java
  libfelix-gogo-command-java libfelix-gogo-runtime-java
  libfelix-gogo-shell-java libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java
  libgeronimo-osgi-support-java libhamcrest-java libicu4j-49-java
  libjetty8-java libllvm3.8:i386 liblucene2-java libmediaart-2.0-0
  libmysqlclient20 libobjenesis-java libodbc1 libopenipmi0
  libosgi-annotation-java libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java
  libosgi-foundation-ee-java libservlet3.0-java libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni
  libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat7-java
  libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 mysql-common python3-gst-1.0 python3-kivy
  python3-kivy-bin python3-kivy-common sat4j
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aidl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
Need to get 83,3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 260 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 aidl amd64 1:6.0.1+r16-1 [83,3 kB]
Fetched 83,3 kB in 0s (197 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package aidl.
(Reading database ... 315744 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../aidl_1%3a6.0.1+r16-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aidl (1:6.0.1+r16-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up aidl (1:6.0.1+r16-1) ...
```

but still I get the following `# Aidl not found, please install it.`:

```
 buildozer android debug deploy run# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
Packages available for installation or update: 2
----------
id: 1 or "tools"
     Type: Tool
     Desc: Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.2
----------
id: 2 or "platform-tools"
     Type: PlatformTool
     Desc: Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1

# Skipping Android SDK update due to spec file setting
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img.xml
Packages available for installation or update: 2
----------
id: 1 or "tools"
     Type: Tool
     Desc: Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.2
----------
id: 2 or "platform-tools"
     Type: PlatformTool
     Desc: Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1

# Aidl not found, please install it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same exact error, and I did a bit of digging, turns out we need to install `build-tools` for the android SDK through Android SDK Manager
**inside our home folder** there is the `.buildozer` hidden directory that `buildozer` created for us
this is the path to the Android SDK Manager: "/home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android"

just need to run android and update the sdk, and aidl will be installed.

Also, Just typing **android** will **only run the executable** if it is in a folder specified in your `$PATH` environment variable (which includes standard locations like /usr/bin). If it's in the current folder, but that folder is not in the `$PATH`, run it with `./android` instead - that is, passing a filepath (which is interpreted unambiguously to run the executable at that destination).

Comment: thanx, it worked. But then I ran into this:
`SystemError: Failed to find jar file: /home/ivan/Downloads/kivy/foo.jar`
could U help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, fixed it by setting

```
android.skip_update = False
```

in the buildozer.spec file.