# Aidl not found error while using buildozer android -v debug

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy, aidl, buildozer

I'm trying to create an android apk file that I can run on my phone using buildozer and kivy. Unfortunately, whenever I run the command `buildozer -v android debug`, the command prompt returns the error `Aidl not found, please install it`.

I've already tried to simply do `sudo apt-get aidl` followed by `sudo apt-get update`, but that still results in the same error.

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant to the issue, but when I open up the file explorer on the ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine, there is a slight "x" on the root folder and it says that I don't have access to open it.

Here is the buildozer.spec file, through I'n note sure if the contents of it are important with this specific error

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UAHekPUatAOrdIU_zFRwoPWgQKd-d0L3QsRXOr2Lo4Q/edit?usp=sharing

Help and suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Note: The reason why I am asking this question is due to the fact that the answer given in [Why does Buildozer show `# Aidl not found, please install it.` even after I installed it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901878/why-does-buildozer-show-aidl-not-found-please-install-it-even-after-i-inst) is out of date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Buildozer show \`# Aidl not found, please install it.\` even after I installed it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901878/why-does-buildozer-show-aidl-not-found-please-install-it-even-after-i-inst)

Comment: The answer is outdated and the filepath to the location in which to install `build-essential` doesn't exist

Comment: What is outdated about it? `Aidl` is still part of the Android SDK `build-tools`. And `build-essential` is not part of the answer.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, I meant that the directory "/home/username/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android" does not exist

Comment: I think you can use any `android` that you can find under the `platform` directory.

Answer (score -3):

Aidl not found, please install it.
Buildozer didn’t install a necessary package

~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.0"
Then press “y” then enter to accept the license.