# Buildozer not finding aidl

Tags: aidl, buildozer

I have installed Docker and am using it with buildozer to create an Android app. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468917/how-to-fix-buildozer-build-fails-with-cmake-error)).

Buildozer now fails with the error:
Home
PUBLIC
 Stack Overflow
Tags
Users
Jobs
Teams Q&A for work Learn More
Title

Body

```
# Check that aidl can be executed
# build-tools folder not found /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools
# Search for Aidl
# Aidl not found, please install it.
```

(See the github thread [here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/413).)

So I created  .../android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools/0/

and copied in /usr/bin/aidl

Buildozer now fails with:

```
# Cwd /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Check that aidl can be executed
# Search for Aidl
# Aidl not found, please install it.
```

As the original github thread has been closed, does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit [30 Apr 2019]

I notice a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727434/aidl-not-found-error-while-using-buildozer-android-v-debug) that has not been answered. Do the people that might know not use Stack-Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem for months and came across [this](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/824), which solved the problem for me.

The error message was misleading; AIDL was present, but the prompt to accept the SDK license and therefore use AIDL was not showing.

When I **set log_level = 2 in the spec file** then I got the correct prompts and error messages.

May be worth trying.

Comment: I've ticked this as it might help someone in  the future.

Comment: Did not work for me.